# Insert PNG at exact position of a video, with exact duration

Tags: ffmpeg

Insert PNG at exact position of a video, with exact duration - is it possible with FFMPEG?

If not, then may be with other software?

I have several hundreds of PNGs. Each needs to be inserted at exact position and displayed until the next PNG comes.

Time intervals between them are irregular. Some should be displayed for 10 seconds, the other - for 2 minutes etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

Overlay "01.png" after 3 seconds for a duration is 4 seconds.

Then overlay "02.png" immediately after the first image for a duration of 5 seconds.

Both images are scaled to 400x300 and positioned in the upper right corner.

The variables make the ffmpeg commands easier to understand.

```bash
# video
v=video.mp4

# image 1
i1=01.png

# image 1 start
i1_s=3

# image 1 duration in seconds
i1_dur=4

# wait after image 1 is displayed for this duration. "0" displays image 2 immediately after image 1
w1=0

# image 2
i2=02.png 

# image 2 duration in seconds
i2_dur=5

# framerate
fr=25

# image width
i_w=400

# image height
i_h=300

ffmpeg \
-i "$v" -framerate $fr \
-i "$i1" -framerate $fr \
-i "$i2" -filter_complex "\
[0:v]scale=1280:720[v0];\
[1:v]fps=$fr,trim=0:$i1_dur,scale=$i_w:$i_h[i1];\
[2:v]fps=$fr,trim=0:$i2_dur,scale=$i_w:$i_h[i2];\
[v0][i1]overlay=W-w-10:10:enable='between(t,$i1_s,$i1_s+$i1_dur)'[v1];\
[v1][i2]overlay=W-w-10:10:enable='between(t,$w1+$i1_s+$i1_dur,$w1+$i1_s+$i1_dur+$i2_dur)'" -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset veryfast output.mp4
```